# Eletrical Field created by a charge surface on a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I was answering this question and even tho i know intuitively that the radial component of the eletric field will cancel out by simmetry, i could not get that in the integral calculation. I´m asking if you can help me figure out what mistake i did in the exercise. Thank you!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If P is a point on the z axis, why is it indicated as a function of φ?

Comment: I think because P has a radius of 0, φ can have any possible value, so if we assume this we can cancel out the component in the direction of φ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the charge is a disk in the xy plane and centered at the origin, then:

d$E_­z$ = z dq/[4π$ε_o(z^2 + r^2)^{1.5}$] and taking dq as a ring of charge in the xy plane, then:

dq = ((20E-6)/r)(2πr)dr.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but what i am trying to figure out is when i go by the more fundamental approach, the radial component is not cancelling in the definite integral, even tho that is what happens.

Comment: It is my understanding that an integral is a scaler sum.  You cannot integrate vectors; only components of vectors.  The 6 m is a z component, so that term can be integrated, but the unit radial vector must be broken into x and y components and each of these becomes a double integral on r and  φ.  Integrating a sine or cosine from zero to 2π gives a zero result.

Comment: Yes, i understand now thank you very much!